# Plasma physics with application to nuclear fusion research internship

Tags: research-level, plasma-physics

I am looking for research opportunities for undergraduates in the field of plasma physics. I have found a couple program like SULI but need several more. I would like to know about more programs out there. Thank you.

Comment: This will almost certainly be closed as of topic—it's a question about a job, not about physics—but I'm sure the denizens of [the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar) would entertain it. The only hitch being that [you need 20 rep](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) on some site in [the network](http://stackexchange.com/sites) before you have full access to chat. Two upvotes on answers or four on question are all it take to get there.

Comment: I suspect that the community may think this question belongs on [academia.se] or another such place, since it's about employment opportunities rather than about physics. But I personally think you might get good answers from this community, so I'll leave it for now.

Comment: I am guessing you are US based, because the last third of the UK "New Scientist" magazine is where they make their money, from advertising all types of career opportunities [New Scientist Jobs](https://jobs.newscientist.com).

Comment: Are you looking for lab or space plasmas? (the following are just places I know that have at least one professor in the field)  For lab plasmas:  Princeton Univ., Univ. of Wisconsin, UCLA.  For space plasmas:  Univ. of Colorado Boulder, UCLA, UC Berkeley, Univ. of Minnesota, Boston Univ., Univ. of New Hampshire, Dartmouth, Johns Hopkins APL, Univ. of Maryland (the main one), Catholic Univ. (in MD), etc.

Comment: I am looking for lab plasma. I have applied to Princeton and Wisconsin. I can't apply for UCLA because of conflicting dates. Thank you.

Comment: @rob this question in its current form would be off topic on Academia SE, as it's a "shopping" question.

Comment: have you tried an REU

Comment: @Goldname yes, I have.

Comment: I think those are the best known programs available. Other than that, you'd have to personally contact professors.